# Embded C# variable inside HTML tags in code behind

Tags: c#, html

I have this line of Code in code behind :

```
string _htmlbody = @"<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
     <p>Thanks Mr: ............ For joing our system</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I have another variable that has user full name (userFullName), How can I embeded the user full name in html tags?

What's the format that should I use in my Silverlight project?

**Update**

I tried below format but does not work :

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: Yes, I want to insert the userFullName insted of (....................)

Comment: `Thanks Mr: " + userFullName + " For joining`...?

Comment: I tried this but does not work

Comment: What happens when you do it? Are you sure that `userFullName` is holding a value?

Comment: I updated the questions, Please check that

Comment: @AbdusalamElsharif: you forgot the `@` for the second string. `Thanks Mr: " + userFullName + @" For joining`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @ElGavilan, Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you concatenate your string, you need to add a verbatim string modifier (`@`) to the second string literal so that it is also recognized as a multi-line string.

```
<p>Thanks Mr: " + ttt + @" For joining</p>
...
```